# Usage of Bitwise OR in the following DOS command

Tags: dos, bit-manipulation

I use the following line of code to execute two commands simultaneously:

```
C:\Users\Me\CLAP.txt | %SystemRoot%\explorer.exe F:\Software
```

Can't help but wonder how the bitwise OR is used to perform the above.

```
C:\Users\Me\CLAP.txt && %SystemRoot%\explorer.exe F:\Software
```

seems to work fine too.

Comment: They're either DOS, or the remnants of DOS which still exist as the Windows command line.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, the | is the pipe symbol, not a bitwise or.  The output of the first command is sent to the input of the next command.

Comment: logical AND connective. If the first program succeeds AND the second program succeeds the whole statement succeeds (otherwise the whole statement fails).